# Can't open modal, when already one modal is showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I can't get: when I'm opening sign_up modal from login modal - everything is working, but when I'm trying to do the same in sign_up modal - it doesn't work.

Here is my code from view and partials:

```
          Buttons
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#login">Login</a>
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#sign_up" >Sign Up</a>
-------------------------------
 <div class="modal hide" id="login">
   <%= render :template => "devise/sessions/new" %> 
 </div>
 <div class="modal hide" id="sign_up">
  <%= render :template => "devise/registrations/new" %>
 </div>
------------------------------
         My redirection links
<%= link_to('or Sign Up', "#sign_up", "data-toggle" => "modal") %>
<%= link_to('or Login', "#login", "data-toggle" => "modal") %>
```

Comment: I found solution for my problem. If someone needs it - tell me.

Comment: you should ALWAYS post the solution, not only of someone asks for it. Please share it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem using this code, when opening login modal from sign_up:

```
 $("#signup").click(function() {//signup - link id
$("#login").removeAttr("static");
$('#login').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

and opening sign_up from login modal:

```
 $("#signin").click(function() {
 $("#sign_up").removeAttr("static");
 $('#sign_up').modal('hide');
 $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
 $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
 });
```